# LaTeX table cells content vertical alignment problem

Tags: latex, tex

I'd like to align text in right cell of table created below, to be vertically align to the top. How to do that ?

```
\begin{tabular}{l|p{3cm}}
    \rule{2cm}{5cm} & Top align content ? \\
\end{tabular}
```

Regards

Comment: why do you have this black box? Maybe what you want can be achieved in another way, so it would help if you explained what you want better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer to second qeustion
You should make your table in the **first** cell to be top aligned.

If you write

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|}  
    \hline text \\ text \\ text\\ text \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
```

then you get a center aligned table.

Write

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}|p{3cm}}  
    \vtop{\vskip 0pt \vskip -\ht\strutbox 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}  
        \hline text \\ text \\ text\\ text \\ \hline 
    \end{tabular}\vskip -\dp\strutbox }%
    & Top align content ? \\  
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\begin{tabular}{l|p{3cm}} 
    \vrule width 2cm height \ht\strutbox depth 5cm & Top align content ! \\ 
\end{tabular}
```